# I have installed Pycharm 2022 but it shows this kind of errors

Tags: python, pycharm

It shows error in console

[image]

I have installed Python 3.11.
and I Restart my pc, but it did not fix, it show that python SDK is invallid
when  I run print("hello") it shows this: Process finished with exit code 101
please anybody help me.

Comment: Please check your venv is correct.  you can try the run the command of console in terminal of Pycharm or Command Prompt of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Pycharm and then uninstalling and reinstalling Python. If that doesn't work, you might need to set Python as the interpreter in Pycharm.

[Here are the instructions on how you can set the interpreter.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#add-existing-interpreter)